# Windows 8 app and SharePoint 2013 Authenticaton

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013, windows-8

I have created a Windows 8 grid app in Visual Studio. This app creates links to  pages in a SharePoint portal, so if a user clicks a tile, it should open a web page within the app frame.

However, each time a user tries to view a page, it asks for SharePoint username and password.

How do I set the authentication to be done automatically in the app? So that when a user tries to view a page it opens it directly.

Note that in the SharePoint portal, authentication is done automatically from the Active Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it is in the app manifest package, check Enterprise Authentication in the capabilities tab.

Comment: Enterprise authentication is not just for SharePoint but for the entire AD based user authentication. glad you found it..